# Please help us to answer this question on History SE!

Tags: discussion

After a discussion on History meta, we have decided we need to take steps to broaden the range of questions that are asked at our stack. Many countries, such as Japan, have a very long recorded history but relatively little history written in the English language.

Most of us on History SE are Anglophones, myself included. I am posting here because you have many intelligent and well-educated users who are familiar with SE, and speak both Japanese and English well.

[Please help us to answer this question,](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/24010/before-the-imposition-of-sakoku-did-any-japanese-people-travel-to-africa-the-m) and even better *ask your own questions* about the history of Japan, and answer them too!